# How can I print an unsigned char in the Xcode console while debugging an iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I print an unsigned char in the Xcode console while debugging an iOS app ?

I've tried print charVar, but it gives me the address only:

```
(const xmlChar *) $11 = 0x15a03878
```

where xmlChar is defined as `typedef unsigned char xmlChar;`

thanks

Comment: Have you tried NSLog? NSLog("%c", Variable);? (Or %d for the numeric value)

Comment: @ATaylor It worked with NSLog(@"%s", Variable); thanks. If you add the answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the %s modifier for viewing this. So it would be `NSLog(@"%s", foo)`

A great reference guide for this stuff can be found here [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)